# In Django, how to re-package a Request.response as a Django response?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-views, python-requests

I have a Django App that accepts messages from a remote device as a POST message.

This fits well with Django's framework!  I used the generic View class (from django.views import View) and defined my own POST function.

But the remote device requires a special reply that I cannot generate in Django (yet).  So, I use the Requests library to re-create the POST message and send it up to the manufacturer's cloud server.

That server processes the data, and responds with the special message in the body. Idealy, the entire HTML response message should go back to the remote device.  If it does not get a valid reply, it will re-send the message.  Which would be annoying!

I've been googling, but am having trouble getting a clear picture on how to either:

(a): Reply back in Django with the Requests.response object without any edits.

(b): Build a Django response and send it back.

Actually, I think I do know how to do (b), but its work.  I would rather do (a) if its possible.

Thanks in Advance!

Rich.

Comment: How does this special reply looks like ? Is it something standard ?

Comment: I can't think of any reason you won't use or subclass the `HttpResponse` class from Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects

Comment: @Kanak: Yes, its an XML document.

Comment: @ClémentDenoix: Yes, I was thinking Django might have such a function or factory already.  I just pass it the response, and it picks out what it needs to create the HTTPresponse.  Just as I wound up doing myself.  As I note below, its such a simple thing I think I really over-thought it to the point of paralysis.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the comments and questions!

The perils of late night programming: you might over-think something, or miss the obvious.  I was so focused on finding a way to return the request.response without any changes/edits I did not even sketch out what option (b) would be.

Well, it turns out its pretty simple:

```
s = Session()
# Populate POST to cloud with data from remote device request:
req = Request('POST', url, data=data, headers=headers)
prepped = req.prepare()
timeout = 10
retries = 3
while retries > 0:
  try:
    logger.debug("POST data to remote host")
    resp = s.send(prepped, timeout=timeout)
    break
  except:
    logger.debug("remote host connection failed, retry")
    retries -= 1
    logger.debug("retries left: %d", retries)
    time.sleep(.3)
    if retries == 0:
      pass # There isn't anything I can do if this fails repeatedly...
# Build reply to remote device:
r = HttpResponse(resp.content, 
                 content_type = resp.headers['Content-Type'], 
                 status = resp.status_code, 
                 reason = resp.reason, 
                 )
r['Server'] = resp.headers['Server']
r['Connection'] = resp.headers['Connection']
logger.debug("Returning Server response to remote device")
return r
```

The Session "s" allows one to use "prepped" and "send", which allows one to monkey with the request object before its sent, and to re-try the send.  I think at least some of it can be removed in a refactor; making this process even simpler.

There are 3 HTTP object at play here:

1. "req" is the POST I send up to the cloud server to get back a special (encrypted) reply.
2. "resp" is the reply back from the cloud server.  The body (.content) contains the special reply.
3. "r" is the Django HTTP response I need to send back to the remote device that started this ball rolling by POSTing data to my view.

Its pretty simple to populate the response with the data, and set headers to the values returned by the cloud server.

I know this works because the remote device does not POST the same data twice!  If there was a mistake anyplace in this process, it would re-send the same data over and over.  I copied the While/try loop from a Socket repeater module.  I don't know if that is really applicable to HTTP. I have been testing this on live hardware for over 48 hours and so far it has never failed. Timeouts are a question mark too, in that I know the remote device and cloud server have strict limits.  So if there is an error in my "repeater", re-trying may not work if the process takes too long. It might be better to just discard/give up on the current POST.  And wait for the remote device to re-try. Sorry, refactoring out loud...

Comment: Genius! This solution is absolutely brilliant.